# SvelteKit is not loading icons from IONICONS

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

I am currently using [ionicons](https://ionic.io/ionicons) as an icon pack for a project, when you manually refresh the page ( cmd + R ) all the icons that were previously rendered disappear. However, when navigating throughout the application via hrefs or on initial load all icons render correctly.

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

1. Add icons ionicons script to the body of app.html
2. Add icon to any svelte page e.g. `<ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon>`
3. Manually refresh the page ( cmd + R etc.... ) and see that icons don't render

See [here](https://github.com/DanSivewright/icon-bug-reproduction) for a reproduction repo of the bug

Comment: One option is to simply use ionicons as SVG in the code. No dependency and they will render prefectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This project choose a very strange and I suppose bad way to distribute the icons.
2. This way is not compatible with most async usagage.
3. They have had a bug about it last 3 years https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/issues/608

You can try this advice https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/issues/646#issuecomment-536150373 but I strongly recommend migrating to a different icon's set. These icons project designed for Ionic Framework or static websites only.